# polymer content select in IE11

Tags: javascript, polymer

DOM rendering differs in chrome and IE11. In chrome it works good but in IE all the values in the `[[item]]` are  together *in one tag*.

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[distChildren]]">
  <px-column label>
    <content select=".item[[item]]"></content>
  </px-column>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add $ after select if you are using dom-repeat.

```
<content select$=".item[[item]]"></content>
```

Comment: can you give some details about your answer?

Comment: @Mitiku following link will help you understand: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding